# Has the determinant of a involution of the first kind ever been considered as an invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, involutions

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $A, B$ be central, simple algebras over $k$ of even degree $n,m > 1$.
Let $\sigma$ be an involution on $A$, which is either symplectic or orthogonal. One way check if an involution is of these types, is to use the fact that for the $k-$vector space
Sym$(A, \sigma) =$ { $x \in A | \sigma(x) = x$ }
one has dim$_k($Sym$(A,\sigma)) = n(n-1)/2$ or $n(n+1)/2$ respectively.

Since $\sigma \in$ Aut$(A)$, such that $\sigma \circ \sigma = id$, we find that the determininant of $\sigma$ must be $1$ or $-1$.

It is well known that a tensorproduct of involutions induces an involution on the respective product of the algebras. If we only consider symplectic and orthogonal involutions, the resulting involution is known to be symplectic or orthogonal as well, while it is symplectic if and only if the number of symplectic factors is odd.
But since det$(\sigma \otimes \tau) = $det$(\sigma)^n $det$(\tau)^m$ for $(A,\sigma), (B,\tau)$ and $n,m$ are even, we can conclude that if the determinant of an involution is $-1$, then it is not decomposable.

**Questions:** Has this property ever considered in the literature? Is an example known, where $n$ is biggen than $2$, i.e. $A$ is not a quaternion algebra?